# Add footer on only last page in Itextshrp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to show footer only on last so i worked with onCloseDocument method

```
public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer,
                            Document document)
```

my code is

```
public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
        base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);
        PdfPTable tabFot = new PdfPTable(1);
        tabFot.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell;
        tabFot.TotalWidth = 50F;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("footer text"));
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = 0f;
        cell.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
        cell.BorderWidthTop = 0f;
        cell.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
        tabFot.AddCell(cell);
        tabFot.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 300, 50, writer.DirectContent);
    }
```

but it's not working for me. I think because of this method is called with the page number equal to the last page plus one.

Any one can help me how can i complete this task.

Comment: Why don't create footer right before You close (finish with creating)  document? To achieve that You don't need `OnCloseDocument` at all.